# Can't install pg gem os X 10.11.6, Rails 5, ruby 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I could not make it work, I tried almost all the solutions on StackOverflow, I tried:

1. Install/Uninstall postgresql with homebrew
2. Specify config file `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config`
3. Remove postgresql with homebrew --force and installing the postgres.app
4. Followed postgres.app docs installing with the command: `sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg`
5. Specifying pg config file of postgres.app `sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin/pg_config`

Anything worked and the error is always the same, the log does not show anything useful...

```
Estebans-MacBook-Air:collegefundme Esteban.E$ sudo env ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64' gem install pg
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/Esteban.E/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.19.0/ext
/Users/Esteban.E/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160922-42901-114ix77.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
checking for PQconnectionUsedPassword()... yes
checking for PQisthreadsafe()... yes
checking for PQprepare()... yes
checking for PQexecParams()... yes
checking for PQescapeString()... yes
checking for PQescapeStringConn()... yes
checking for PQescapeLiteral()... yes
checking for PQescapeIdentifier()... yes
checking for PQgetCancel()... yes
checking for lo_create()... yes
checking for pg_encoding_to_char()... yes
checking for pg_char_to_encoding()... yes
checking for PQsetClientEncoding()... yes
checking for PQlibVersion()... yes
checking for PQping()... yes
checking for PQsetSingleRowMode()... yes
checking for PQconninfo()... yes
checking for PQsslAttribute()... yes
checking for rb_encdb_alias()... yes
checking for rb_enc_alias()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_fd_select()... yes
checking for rb_w32_wrap_io_handle()... no
checking for rb_str_modify_expand()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for PGRES_COPY_BOTH in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for PGRES_SINGLE_TUPLE in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for PG_DIAG_TABLE_NAME in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for struct pgNotify.extra in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for ruby/st.h... yes
checking for C99 variable length arrays... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/Esteban.E/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0/pg-0.19.0/mkmf.log

current directory: /Users/Esteban.E/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.19.0/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean
/Users/Esteban.E/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:270:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem make (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /Users/Esteban.E/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:298:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /Users/Esteban.E/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/make:22:in `<main>'
    from /Users/Esteban.E/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/Esteban.E/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'

current directory: /Users/Esteban.E/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.19.0/ext
make "DESTDIR="
/Users/Esteban.E/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:270:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem make (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /Users/Esteban.E/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:298:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /Users/Esteban.E/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/make:22:in `<main>'
    from /Users/Esteban.E/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/Esteban.E/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'

make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Esteban.E/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.19.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Esteban.E/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0/pg-0.19.0/gem_make.out
```

I spent a lot of hours trying to solve it myself, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you try `gem update --system` and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Pull up a Terminal session and run `brew doctor`. I bet it complains that your xcode command line tools are out of date.

Comment: I did `gem update --system` nothing changed the log is the same, also I did `brew doctor` even `brew update` but still the same =/

Answer (score 2):

If you upgraded xcode after last gem pg install/upgrade, you should agree with xcode license

`sudo xcodebuild -license`

Unfortunately pg build fails with odd messages without this step.